# Is it a good practice to use require_once in the .blade.php template?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

Normally we'll use something like

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php'; //file for start the session, connect to database etc.
?>
<!-- HTML Content Here-->
head body etc.
<!---------------------->
```

But when you're building a .blade.php template. Is thing also work that way?
I mean my template is something like

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/tpl.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/fonts/font.css">
</head>
<body>
    @yield('header')

    @yield('content')

    @yield('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a best practice or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I guess that you are trying in laravel. If so Using `require` for implementing session is extremely bad practice.Do you want me to suggest a better way in laravel ?

Comment: This would definitely help you: https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial

Comment: Please do so @SulthanAllaudeen this is the first time I use laravel also it's the first time I use mvc.

Comment: Ok, writing answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to Study the **Laravel Authentication** which doesn't require such steps.

Laravel already handles such works for you.

Here is the [Laravel Authentication Document](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#authenticating-users)

If you are using Laravel 4.2, then

In your routes, you should add the

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){ #Your Request here});
```

**Here is the sample route for your**

```
Route::get('home', 'YourControllerr@YourGeneralFunction');
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
Route::get('dashboard', 'YourControllerr@YourSecureFunction');
});
```

In the Above routes the url `home` can be accessed by anyone (Public). But the url `dashboard` can be only accessed by the logged in user.

If you are using the **Laravel 5** or above, then it is even simple

You can simply check the user by

If they user is guest then

```
@if(Auth::guest())
```

Or if the user is authenticated then

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

or

```
@if( Auth::check() )
    Current user: {{ Auth::user()->name }}
@endif
```

Comment: So I don't need to use the session_start at the beginning of the page anymore right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
include"init.php";
```

or

```
include_once"init.php";
```

reference http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp